# Power Series Center

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

If the interval of convergence is $(-\infty,\ \infty)$ then the radius will be infinite. But what will happen to the center? Will it stay the same?

Comment: Yes the center stays the same.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, convergence near the center is good, but if the radius is larger, the convergence is better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are considering a power series around that center, it does by definition. But if the radius of convergence is $\infty$, your function can be extended to a holomorphic function $f(z)$, and the Taylor series around any real or complex argument will have an infinite radius of convergence, too. That can be practical: the power series for $e^z$ around $0$ converges for all arguments, but it doesn't converge really very well for the argument $-1000$, say, especially numerically.